# Scraping from middle of string with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have the following string:

> name(name, **content(content, content, content)**, number)

And I need the part bolded out. Is there a way to do this using regex? Essentially I think I need a way of saying:

*take all characters until this pattern is hit: , number)*

Comment: Is it prefixed like 'content(' ? Then you could just take the substring of 'content(' with a length until the next ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a regex? If not you might make it more readable with substring.

In your case something like:

```
var str = "name(name, content(content, content, content), number)";
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(',')) + str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',')) );
```

should work.
(I assume it's C# because of the tag)

Answer (score 1):

You can try simple one:

```
(\w+\([^\(\)]*\))
```

and your code:

```
var result = Regex.Match(inputString,
                     @"(\w+\([^\(\)]*\))")
                     .Groups[1].Value;
```

explain:

```
\w+            word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
               (1 or more times)
\(             character '('
[^\(\)]*       any character except: '\(', '\)' 
               (0 or more times)
\)             character ')'
```

orthis complete mode:

```
\w+\s*\(?<yourCon>\w+,\s*([^\)]*\))\s*,\s*\w+\s*\)
```

and your code like this:

```
var result = Regex.Match(inputString, 
                         @"\w+\s*\(?<yourCon>\w+,\s*([^\)]*\))\s*,\s*\w+\s*\)")
                         .Groups["yourCont"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a match group there, then access it with [`Match.Groups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx).

A regex like this perhaps?

```
.*, (.*\)),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try this:

```
\bcontent\([^\)]+[\)],
```

It means:

```
From the word boundary, find "content(" literally.
Match any character that is not a ), greedily
Match a )
Match a ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Regex and pull of the first group result.

```
(?:.+?\(.+?, )(.+?\))
```

And here is a very small example of how you will use it.

```
var input = "name(name, content(content, content, content), number)
var pattern = @"(?:.+?\(.+?, )(.+?\))";

var results = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (results.Success)
{
    var value = results.Groups[0];
}
```